# Why I am getting access violation error for my large 1D array in C?

Tags: c

I am reading a csv file (having data in the first column but multiple rows). For that I have to initialize a vector to store data in. This works fine for small files but for large files such that this one with no. of rows as 10210672, it gives memory access violation error. I have initialized the array as following.

```
char *token_vector[filesize];
```

This is where i am reading csv file.

```
while(index<(file_npdws-1)
    {
        pick = abs(pick-1);
        (pointer = fgets(byte_temp,sizeof(byte_temp)*2,file));
        if(pointer!=NULL)
        {
            token= strtok(pointer,",");
            token_vector[index] = strdup(token);
        }

            noofpulses++;
        index++;

        //printf("\n Total Pulses : %d", noofpulses);
    }
```

And this is where the error comes i.e. where I read & translate this array to decimal

```
for(j = 0;j<file_npdws-1;j++)
{
 OV[i] =  (hex2dec(token_vector[j][20])*16+hex2dec(token_vector[j][21])*1);
 i++;
}
```

The error comes at around 9millionth value of i and j whereas max value should go to 10210672.
P.S: My pc is 64 bit with RAM 32GB. And I am using visual studio 2010 with C language. [My error screenshot is attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPfOA.png)

Also I have tried allocating memory on heap due to limitation of stack but the same issue continues.
This is how I initialized heap array `const char** token_vector = (char**)malloc((filesize)*sizeof( char*) );` It was not accepting single * aster-stick.
When I declare it a heap array as below

```
const char* token_vector = (char*)malloc((filesize/2)*sizeof( char*) );
```

I get error in building the code which says : intellisense: expression must have pointer-to-object type. I get this error at the line
 `OV[i] =  (hex2dec(token_vector2[k][20])*16+hex2dec(token_vector2[k][21])*1);`
[See my error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTd4V.png)

Any help would really be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: `index` is never defined nor initialized. please post the real code.

Comment: Show a fully compilable code example, it is very unclear what you mean with those small snippets. The maximum stack size for most operating systems is 4kilobytes, so big variable length arrays fail on you system. Use dynamic allocation. `expression must have pointer-` - please post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - a minimal complete verificable example of your code that would let others reproduce the problem. I want to test your errors - what code should I copy into my intellisense to get the same error?

Comment: Remove all parts of "real code" until you are left with the smallest code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: *Program is too large* is not a reason. A single field CSV file can be read in with a 10-line demonstration program.

Comment: @KamilCuk — the default stack size on Windows is normally 1 MiB and on Unix-like platforms, it is normally 8 MiB.  I don’t know of a system where it is only 4 KiB. The rest of your comment is valid, though.

Comment: `char *token_vector[filesize]; ` is not the same as `const char* token_vector = ...`

Comment: @JonathanLeffler IIRC, the stacksize in the Linux kernel is only 4 KiB - a single page of memory.  So such small stacks do exist in some contexts. I know when I was writing Linux kernel modules the available stack was very small, and the results from overflowing the stack were not good...

Comment: Note: there is a `)` missing in: `while(index<(file_npdws-1)` Or: the second `(` is not needed, anyway)

Comment: @wildplasser ) was missed while copying the code here. I got your point though.

Comment: @KamilCuk here is my MCVE https://drive.google.com/file/d/1l9JdT8Lo46UpkO5KM070woNUnC15-uio/view?usp=sharing

Comment: No, PLEASE don't put source code or screenshots somewhere in the web. Instead [edit] your question so that it is instantly readable, and provide a [example] like KamilCuk suggested already.

Answer (score 0):

My issue has been resolved. The issue was in the following line

```
 token_vector[index] = strdup(token);
```

"strdup" [duplicates the string](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/strdup-strdndup-functions-c/) and is never freed which is why the heap memory is being consumed incrementally as I saw it reached around 1.6GB in the task manager by this application. I have removed this line as it was not quite doing anything and my code is working fine. But thank you all for responding to my query.